# What exactly is Implies? Is it a logical test?

Tags: logic

I ran the following to simplify my logical test (expecting something in terms of `And` and `Or` ...)

```
FullSimplify[Not[a] || (a && b)]
```

and was surprised to see

> $a \Rightarrow b$ `(*Implies[a, b]*)` .

I thought "implies" is a statement you deduce from a set of truths.  Since when is "implies" a logical test?

Just for fun I tried

```
Implies[1 > 2, 3 > 4]
(*True*)
```

Is *Mathematica* actually trying to say that if 1 is greater than 2, then 3 must be greater than 4?

Comment: The docs seem pretty clear.  What's the problem?  (The answer to your last question is "yes" on logical grounds that have nothing to do with *Mathematica* per se.)

Comment: Yes, $A \text{ implies } B$ is a logical operation, just like $A \text{ and } B$ or  $A \text{ xor } B$. Does [this](http://planetmath.org/logicalimplication) answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the literal sense, asserting that A "implies" B (or A ⇒ B) means that if A is true, B must also be true. It says nothing about B when A is false. Therefore:

- When A is true, B must also be true (because of the implication itself).
- When A is false, we don't know anything about B, so B could be either true or false.

The binary operation "A implies B" will give true if the given A and B match either of the above statements, answering the question "Could A imply B?", and thus:

```
   A   |   B   | Could A imply B?
-------+-------+------------------
 True  | True  | Yes
 True  | False | No
 False | True  | Yes
 False | False | Yes
```

You can see that case 2 is the only one where you can undoubtedly deny that A ⇒ B.

Indeed, "B OR NOT A" is another way to express the above truth table.

Take a look at the following Wikipedia article:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional

Answer (score 7):

The logical simplification of `Not[a] || (a && b)` is indeed `Implies[a,b]`.  You can see this by comparing the logical truth tables:

```
Table[{a, b, Not[a] || (a && b)}, 
  {a, {False, True}}, 
  {b, {False, True}}] // MatrixForm
```

is the same as

```
Table[{a, b, Implies[a, b]}, 
   {a, {False, True}}, 
   {b, {False,  True}}] // MatrixForm
```

Likewise the logical simplification of `False` implies `False` is `True`.

```
Implies[False, False]
```

(* True *)

You are incorrect the state that "if 1 is greater than 2, then 3 must be greater than 4."  Note that `Implies[1 > 2, 4 > 3]` is *also* `True`.  Thus from a false premise you can deduce anything.... a well-known fact from formal logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
 FullSimplify[Not[a] || (a && b)] // InputForm
```

Implies[a, b]

```
Simplify[Not[a] || (a && b)]
```

! a || b

```
BooleanConvert[Implies[a, b]]
```

! a || b

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{a, b, ! a || b}, {a, b}],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {a, b, ! a || b}}]
```

[image]